# Spring LDAP returning exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm using Spring 3.2.7 and Spring Security 3.2.0

I'm using Apache DS 2.0.0 on my local Windows computer.  All of the users have their passwords stored as plain text, no encryption.

I have the following defined in my spring config XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">         
    <security:http auto-config="true" >         
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/hello" access="ROLE_SCARVAREZ_MEMBER" />      
<security:form-login/>  
    </security:http>        
    <security:authentication-manager>
                            <security:ldap-authentication-provider 
                            user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people"
                            group-search-base="ou=groups" 
                            group-search-filter="(member={0})"
                            >
                            </security:ldap-authentication-provider>        
    </security:authentication-manager>      
    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=com" />      
    </beans>
```

I get the default Spring login form.  However, when I attempt to log in, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapEncoder
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticator.getUserDns(AbstractLdapAuthenticator.java:95)
    org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:178)
    org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:61)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

I can't figure out what JAR file I need to include to get past this exception.

I'm not using Maven, but here are the JAR files in my project:

```
aopalliance.jar 
aspectj-1.7.2.jar 
aspectjweaver-1.7.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar 
log4j-1.2.17.jar
sl4j-api-1.7.5.jar 
spring-aop-3.2.7.jar 
spring-aspects-3.2.7.jar
spring-beans-3.2.7.jar 
spring-context-3.2.7.jar 
spring-core-3.2.7.jar
spring-expression-3.2.7.jar 
spring-jdbc-3.2.7.jar
spring-ldap-core-2.0.1.jar 
spring-ldapcore-tiger.2.0.1.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.0.jar 
spring-security-core.3.2.0.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.jar 
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.0.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.jar 
spring-tx-3.2.7.jar 
spring-web-3.2.7.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.7.jar
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you include all the the class path? try adding them to the buildpath lib tab. The rquired jar is in your lib folder which is spring-ldap-core-2.0.1.jar

Comment: @Zeus Thanks for responding.  That JAR is included with the WAR when I build the application via Ant.  I can see it in the deployed WAR file's WEB-INF/lib folder.  I checked the JAR file using 7-Zip and that class is not in there.

Comment: You may have to try previous versions of stable jars of the ldap-core.jar

Comment: @Zeus I will try some older versions of that Jar.  I thought it would be good when I downloaded it from the Maven repository.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, saves all the trouble, Gradle is also good, if you want to use that.

Comment: Solution was to use spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar